# Make Gradle include all sources from entire dependency tree

Tags: java, gwt, jar, gradle

Gradle is an excellent dependency manager. However, there does not seem to be an obvious way with the Java plugin to pull the source artifacts from an entire dependency tree.

Building with [GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/) requires `.java` source files, not `.class` bytecode files.

When declaring dependencies among my own Gradle projects, I can define a custom Gradle *configuration* and extend the `Jar` task type to produce a custom source artifact. From the parent project, I can then easily rely on the subproject's sources in a loosely-coupled way.

But what if my subproject then relies on some non-source dependencies from `mavenCentral()`? How do I get the parent project to pull the sources from those transitive dependencies (the whole tree), assuming they are available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't an easy way to resolve a configuration's source Jars at the moment. (You'd essentially have to reimplement what the `eclipse` and `idea` plugins do). The next Gradle version (1.12) will provide a new artifact resolution API, which will make this a lot easier.